# How to connect MySQL server to Blue Prism?

Tags: mysql, blueprism

I tried using VBO "Data - SQL Server", by giving the server name as "MySQL Server 8.0", I also gave database name (which is already created) and credentials

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not a SQL Server; they are two mutually exclusive RDBMS', each with their own connection methodologies. The `Data - SQL Server` VBO will *not* work to connect Blue Prism with a MySQL-based database server. Further, MySQL connections are not supported in Blue Prism out of the box, considering their limited deployment in enterprise environments.

*However*, you should hypothetically be able to install the [Cherry City Software MySQL OLEDB Provider](https://cherrycitysoftware.com/Products/MySQLProvider) on your Interactive Clients and Runtime Resources to allow the `Data - OLEDB` VBO to connect and query against your MySQL instance with the following connection string ([source](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-oledb-mysqlprov/)):

```
Provider=MySQLProv;Data Source=db_name;User Id=db_user;Password=db_password;
```

... replacing the values for `db_name`, `db_user`, and `db_password` with your own.

Comment: Why use this 9 year old provider instead of eg MySQL's Connector/ODBC? I'd expect it to have serious issues connecting to MySQL 8.0 which was released only last year. Even Microsoft advises people to use the ODBC drivers for SQL Server for at least the last 3 years

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To my knowledge Blue Prism doesn't support ODBC connectors out of the box. Based on my perception of the OP's experience with the tool and SQL itself, the solution I've provided above leverages as much built-in functionality as possible. I would agree that using a more up-to-date ODBC connector would be helpful, but ultimately I've balanced that with the complexity of such an implementation.

Comment: That's bad for Blue Prism. How will it connect to SQL Server? A simple connection to a database is far easier and easier than any RPA tool btw. If one has SQL Server and SSIS (even VS Community with SSDT would do) one could just connect using SSIS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Blue Prism provides a re-usable set of methods for SQL Server which leverage `System.Data.SqlClient` under the hood; I'd assume this helps clients with backward-compatibility (SQL Server 2000+) and performance requirements.

Comment: [Introducing the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient will be the only place we will be implementing new features going forward`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I personally would agree with your point about SSIS. However, Blue Prism is designed to be used by business users to design and deploy automated processes in an enterprise. I highly doubt that the average business user will have the technical know-how to implement SSIS if it doesn't have a pre-built connector out of the box.